# Jquery radio buttons php array

Tags: jquery, input, onchange

I have these checkboxes

```
<table>
                <?php 
                    foreach($membership_type as $key => $membership) {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'. form_label($membership['name'], $membership['name']) .'</td>'; 
                        echo '<td>'. 
form_checkbox(array("name"=>"membershiptype[]","id"=>$membership['name'], "value"=>$membership['id'], "checked"=>set_radio("membershiptype", $membership['id'], FALSE))) .'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. form_label('$'. $membership['fee'], $membership['name']) .'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    } 
                ?>
                </table>
```

I am trying to write a jquery script to alert something if the checkboxes change...this what I got so far, but no alert appears

```
$("input[name='membershiptype']").change(function() {
            alert('hi');
        })
```

Any help would be awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct name of the checkboxes is `membershiptype[]`, so don't skip the brackets:

```
$("input[name='membershiptype[]']").change(function() {
    alert("hi");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gVKnL/